# Android: Adding another table row programmatically

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I have a TableLayout with one Table Row inside it. I am trying to use the function below to add another TableRow with the same values as the already existing table row:

```
tableRowOne = findViewById(R.id.tableRowOne);
editTextOne = findViewById(R.id.editTextOne);

public void AddTableRowFunction() {        

    TableRow tableRowNew = new TableRow(this);
    tableRowNew = tableRowOne;

    EditText editTextNew = new EditText(this);

    editTextNew = editTextPlayer1;

    tableRowNew.addView(editTextNew);

    table.addView(tableRowNew, 0 ,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

}
```

But the app crashes when I call the function telling me that " The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Comment: check if you already added the view

Answer (score 0):

When a `View` is added to a `ViewGroup`, it holds a reference to the parent. As you add same view to your table every time, this issue is happened. It is because of this:

```
tableRowNew = tableRowOne;
```

Try to remove above line, because every time you have tried to add `tableRowNew`, you have tried to add a view which is previously added to the `table`.

Comment: The same happens when just copying the EditText. The editTextPlayer1 is on the already shown table row. Can I copy the details about It without having this problem?

Comment: I think you should design your views in a xml layout. Then using LayoutInflater make an instance of it. By adding this view, the problem will not happen.